# Improper Initialization of 2D Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to construct a 2D array for an assignment. I've used a nested for loop to construct the 2D array using scanf():

```
  int width;
  int height;

  scanf("%d %d",&width,&height);

  int array[width][height];

  for (int i=0;i<height;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<width;j++){
      scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
    }
  }
```

However when I print the array, I can see that it has been constructed in a strange way, where all the numbers of the first line past a certain point are the first few numbers from the second line (instead of what they should be). The next lines after work fine.

Example:

Input:

6 2

1 3 5 7 9 1

2 4 6 8 0 2

3 4 2 0 1 3

The created array looks like this:

1 3 2 4 6 8 (<-- these last 4 numbers are the first 4 numbers of the second line)

2 4 6 8 0 2 (correct)

3 4 2 0 1 3 (correct)

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You swapped `width` and `height` in the loop, either you do `int array[height][width]` or you swap the conditions `i<width` and `j<height`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I swapped the loops, but still have a problem.

The output is now:
135791
579124

So it is still incorrect, it's just the first 4 numbers of the 2nd line that are incorrect now.

Comment: check my answer, swapping the array declaration fixes the problem. See https://ideone.com/OJjj0Y

Comment: @callum202 I suspect a problem with the example input or display code. Can you post that? Notice that you say the input is `6 2` for size but that would give you two rows not three. Likewise, you seem to be giving it many numbers---so perhaps that's a typo.

Comment: @Steve thanks Steve, Pablo correctly identified the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of `array`

```
int array[width][height];
```

is wrong. The outer loop goes from 0 to `height - 1`, but `array[i]` can only go
from 0 to `width - 1`. The same applies for the inner loop. You swapped `width`
and `height` in the declaration of the array, it should be

```
int array[height][width];
```

Also note that for the matrix

```
1 3 5 7 9 1
2 4 6 8 0 2
3 4 2 0 1 3
```

the width is 6 and the height is 3, so the correct input should be

```
6 3
1 3 5 7 9 1
2 4 6 8 0 2
3 4 2 0 1 3
```

I compiled and run this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int width;
  int height;

  scanf("%d %d",&width,&height);

  int array[height][width];

  for (int i=0;i<height;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<width;j++){
      scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
    }
  }

  printf("----------------\n");

  for (int i=0;i<height;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<width;j++){
      printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }


}
```

And the output is:

```
$ ./b 
6 3
1 3 5 7 9 1
2 4 6 8 0 2
3 4 2 0 1 3
----------------
1 3 5 7 9 1 
2 4 6 8 0 2 
3 4 2 0 1 3
```

as you can see, now it's reading correctly. See https://ideone.com/OJjj0Y

Comment: Ah great, that fixed it. Yeah I tried your suggestion before but forgot to switch the [height] and [width] in the initialization of the array. Now it works. Thanks a lot for helping me!